# Java/NetBeans: Uploading javadoc to FTP-Server

Tags: java, netbeans, documentation, javadoc

Does NetBeans support an automatic upload of the newest Documentation, whenever I build my application or run the javadoc?
Do you know a plugin for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new ant target with [FTP task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html). If you don't know much about ant, take a look at [this tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorials.html).